# Breaking code into manageable chunks

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application written in C# and one of the forms has an enourmous amount of code with it. I have made extensive use of classes to keep the forms code to a minimum, but because the form has a number of tab pages and hundreds of controls and datagrids, etc., the code on the form itself is still extensive.

Is there any way to break this code into more manageable and smaller items, perhaps one item in the solution for each tab page, whilst keeping all the code in the same scope?

Comment: You could always use partial classes. And then try to separate presentation concerns from the rest. A MVP architecture works just as well for Winforms.

Comment: Not that I condone it.. however partial classes may be suitable for you (if you're the only developer)..

Comment: are you looking for restructuring you code or just want to manage the existing codes.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your looking for better readability and maintainance without moving the code around too much, you could use:

```
#region Tab 1
#region Variables
#endregion
#region Properties
#endregion
#region Methods
#endregion
 #endregion
```

This would allow you to minimise parts of the code you are not interested in while making changes to a certain tab. It's not perfect, but it may help.

Comment: thank you - that helps make it easier navigating back and forth

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the restructuring the code and its framework then you must be aware of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles. A good article for it is *[S.O.L.I.D. Software Development, One Step at a Time](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=1001061&page=3)*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) to split code into several cs files, but I really don't see to much benefit in that, only solution is to do full refactoring and remove code that has nothing to do with UI into separate classes.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring). This is a common problem with classic [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) applications, so you have to be disciplined and decide how to tidy up. It's not going to be an instantaneous fix.

Lookup [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)/[MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), even [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and learn how others break their code up. From there you can introduce a tiered architecture that suits you.

However, you aren't alone. The refactoring tools in Visual Studio or even better in [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) can automate a lot of the copy paste cycle, eliminating errors and automatically keeping variable names, etc. in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Code which belongs to the presentation layer of a user control you can put into a class which extends the control.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the code out of each tab and create a user control to contain the code for each tab. (you could even inherit from TabPage and add these to the form on init)

Then the user controls can be added in to each tab and should reduce code significantly.

The grids etc can also be turned in to user controls exposing the minimum number of methods and properties required for the other controls to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining form controls over and over, just create a new instance of them on your other tab.

Create getter and setter to access this.

But really, there is no problem with having lots of code for form controls, its just the way it is I think. I thought Visual Studio was supposed to generate all this for you using [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)?

Answer (score 0):

I personally have trouble with regions. It sometimes throws the editor and you need to close and re-open the file to reset it (I am working with [Boo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_%28programming_language%29) in [SharpDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop), and it may be specific to that), so for large forms with tabs I tend to use partial classes.

A neat trick you can do in Visual Studio/SharpDevelop file explorer is to drag the file for the partial class onto the main file for the class, so they all sit nested under MainForm (next to the `.designer` and `.resx` files) which just keeps things neater.